# How many instances of Class literals can be there residing in the JVM?

Tags: java, reflection

I have never specifically worked with `class literals` . I think they are mostly used in reflection apis . I want to understand how many instances can be there for class literals ? Are they `instance controlled` (for example Singletons?)

```
Class<String> stringClass = String.class;
```

Comment: Class is loaded as Object in Heap by Class Loader on JVM Startup...so only one class literal instance exists per class loader... however you can create as many objects of type class in your code...

Comment: One `Class` object per class, predictably enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Class object is (at least in theory) created when the class is loaded.  There is only one per class.  It's not correct to refer to it as a singleton, though, since there are multiple Class objects, each for a given class, just as you can have multiple String objects with different values.

Note that you can have two different Class objects named "a.b.c", if they are loaded by different class loaders.  These would be two distinct classes (which may not even be similar) and two distinct Class objects.

Comment: "There is only one per class" isn't *quite* the full story -- there are also the oddball `int.class`, `float.class`, and even `void.class`.  These are instances of `Class` that correspond to primitive types.

Comment: @Hot Licks I have two doubts . 1) Why in the first line you say "in theory " ? 2) Can you elaborate on your second paragraph ? I couldn't follow it .

Comment: I say "in theory" because the actual Class object is a dummy -- a "front" for a massive data structure.  It could be created in a "lazy" fashion, on first reference, rather than when the class is loaded.  In practice, though, it's probably created with the actual class, since it's usually referred to shortly after class loading.  As to the second part, you can always have multiple classes of the same name, but loaded under different class loaders -- look it up.

Answer (score 0):

Class is loaded as Object in Heap by Class Loader.

So only one **class literal instance** exists per class loader.

However you can create as many instances of type class in your code.

Comment: Actually, it's not a "class literal instance", it's an instance of Class which you can refer to with a literal notation from Java source.  The object "behind" the literal is the same Class object you'd get if you explicitly asked the ClassLoader for it.

Comment: @hotlicks true..I tried to put in words a different way so as its clear... :-) .... instance of class can also mean instance objects of class...